# What to set as the Provider's value using react typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript, react-context

I'm trying to learn how to use hooks and context in React, but need to work with TypeScript (new to that as well).

I am confused about what to set provider value on my below code. I have created a hook useFirebase it will return some functions like RegisterUser, SignIn, user(it's a state), logout.

First I created UseAuth.tsx hook, using this hook I want to import the above functions which I mentioned.

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthProvider';

const UseAuth = () => {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
    return auth
};

export default UseAuth;
```

Everything is ok but I am getting an error on the provider value. The error is `(JSX attribute) React.ProviderProps<null>.value: null Type '{ RegisterUser: RegisterUserFunction; SignIn: SignInUserFunction; user: userState; logout: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'null'. The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<null>'` I have created an interface **IAuth** but where I need to define it I am confused.

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { UseFirebase } from '../hooks/UseFirebase';


export const AuthContext = createContext(null)

export interface IAuth {
    RegisterUser: () => void;
    SignIn : () => void;
    user : any
    logout : () => void;

}

const AuthProvider = ({ children } :any) => {
    const allContext = UseFirebase()
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={allContext}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in

```
export const AuthContext = createContext(null)
```

You need to pass a proper type to it, so it won't complain when trying to assign any value.

Try something like

```
 React.createContext<IAuth>(initialValue);
```

For a more detailed explanation check out this article [react-context-with-typescrip](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-context-with-typescript/)